# How to make an relative search ( informed by user )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a lot of checkboxs like those :
[image]

The user will check one param of each checkbox to make the search.

How can I do that relative search informed by the user ? Isn't obligatted to select one of each checkbox.

My JS:

```
var checkeds = new Array();
$("input[name='marcar[]']:checked").each(function (){
    checkeds.push( $(this).val());
});
var obj = $("#paramsPesquisa");
if($(obj).find("input[id='cd_seq_pedido']:checked").length > 0){
    var cd_seq_pedido = $(obj).find("input[id='cd_seq_pedido']:checked").val();
}else{
    var cd_seq_pedido = "";
}
```

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/checkbox_marcados",
    data: {
        'marcar':checkeds,
        'cd_seq_pedido': cd_seq_pedido,
        'cd_pedido': cd_pedido
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    } 
});
```

On my controller, how can I make this query ?

```
$pesquisa = $this->PesquisaPedOnline->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('cd_seq_pedido', 'cd_pedido', 'ds_cpl_tamanho_interno'),
    'conditions' => array(?????)
));
```

If need more information, I'll put, sorry if I couldn't explain clearly.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the conditions array in Cake you need to specify what field each of the checkbox values corresponds with. For example:

```
$conditions = array(
    'ModelName.fieldname1' => 'value1', // a single checkbox value
    'ModelName.fieldname2' => 'value2, value3, value4', // multiple checkbox values
    // etc...
);
```

To be able to construct the `$conditions` array like this you need to pass more information to the controller in your ajax call. I would suggest constructing a JSON object so you can build something like `{'fieldname1':'value1, value2'}`.

Also you may want to consider how to remove items that the user unchecks.

Comment: But if the first checkbox it's checked, and second isn't checked ? How to mount that query ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the search plugin: https://github.com/cakedc/search

The name is a little misleading, it actually implements the PRG pattern and deals with the transformation of a POST request into search conditions.

This is a lot more clean than doing a huge amount of if-else checks on the POST data manually. Just take a look at the examples and  tutorials, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Can I ask you for some practice example ? I already read the Docs from the link... You could explain to me how to use on my case ? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I think the documentation is sufficient, just try it. Sorry, I don't have the time and mood to write example code for this right now.